# Using Apache Commons Digester with JSON

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-digester

I am writing a class that extends a class that uses Digester to parse an XML response from an API (Example [existing class](https://github.com/camsys/onebusaway-nyc/blob/08e138c84e739fc58d9132c1cfeab673ee9efc74/onebusaway-nyc-presentation/src/main/java/org/onebusaway/nyc/geocoder/impl/GoogleGeocoderImpl.java#L151), code snipper below). After receiving the response, the code creates an object and adds specific methods on that.

Code snippet edited for brevity:

```
      private Digester createDigester() {
        Digester digester = new Digester();

        digester.addObjectCreate("GeocodeResponse/result", GoogleGeocoderResult.class);
        digester.addObjectCreate("GeocodeResponse/result/address_component", GoogleAddressComponent.class);
        digester.addCallMethod("GeocodeResponse/result/address_component/long_name", "setLongName", 0);
...
        digester.addSetNext("GeocodeResponse/result/address_component", "addAddressComponent");

        Class<?>[] dType = {Double.class};
        digester.addCallMethod("GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address", "setFormattedAddress", 0);
...
        digester.addSetNext("GeocodeResponse/result", "add");
        return digester;
      }
    }
```

The API that I will be calling, however, only supports JSON. I have found a probable [solution](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.uima/AlchemyAPIAnnotator/2.3.1/org/apache/uima/alchemy/digester/json/JsonDigester.java), which involves converting the JSON to XML and then running it through Digester, but that seems incredibly hackish.

```
public JsonDigester(final String customRootElementName) {
    super(new JsonXMLReader(customRootElementName));
  }
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

#### This class is specifically meant to deal with XML as per the documentation:

> Basically, the Digester package lets you configure an XML -> Java
> object mapping module, which triggers certain actions called rules
> whenever a particular pattern of nested XML elements is recognized. A
> rich set of predefined rules is available for your use, or you can
> also create your own.

Why would you think it would work with JSON?

Comment: Yes, that is the question. Is there a less hacky way to accept the JSON encoded object? The abstract I am extending class appears to rely on Digester.

Comment: Yes there is a less hacky way, use XML to begin with like it requires or do not use it.